# Adverse or averse?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

I have been thinking about these two words for quite a while. I have looked up the dictionary on these two words and it seemed as if the two words are not identical. However, there are claims of the two words being easily misunderstood. So, I would like to know what exactly are the differences between the two words(if any). A sample sentence would also be appreciated.

Comment: I think you misread the dictionary. [Adverse](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adverse?q=adverse) and [averse](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/averse?q=averse) are not alike.

Comment: Yes they are. They come from a common root that indicates turning. _Averse_ (stressed on the second syllable) is an adjective that means turning away from something in dislike (_He's averse to politics_), while _adverse_ (stressed on the first syllable) is an adjective that describes (and often modifies) circumstances, meaning that the situation has turned on one and become difficult (_In adverse conditions like this blizzard, they won't expect you at work_); the "turning" is metaphorical, but it's enough to confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While they are both adjectives, *averse* is [having a strong feeling of opposition, antipathy, repugnance](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/averse?s=t), etc.

In contrast, *[adverse](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adverse)* is:

1. unfavorable or antagonistic in purpose or effect: *adverse criticism.*
2. opposing one's interests or desire: *adverse circumstances.*
3. being or acting in a contrary direction; opposed or opposing: *adverse winds.*
4. opposite; confronting: *the adverse page.*

In short: *Someone* would feel averse about something. *Something* would be adverse.

> I am averse to poverty. Dilbert's friend, Wally, is averse to work of any kind.
>
> Poverty is an adverse circumstance. The Pointy-Haired Boss provides a hailstorm of adverse criticism.