# Proper usage of the word 'averse'

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Is it proper English to make a statement such as the one below?

> I am train averse.

As a native English speaker, it seems to be correct but when I take a closer look at the structure, it doesn't seem like a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: Technically I think it needs a hyphen, like with risk-averse. Because you're making it into one word, into an adjective.

Comment: It's modelled on 'risk-averse' (which is hyphenated even when used predicatively) but, as it seems to be listed in no dictionaries, seems not to be part of the lexicon. You need to define 'proper English' before a 'proper answer' can be given. I'd use it in informal situations or (for first mention) in scare-quotes. Note that it could be interpreted in more than one way: averse to trains (like a dog I knew), or averse to using trains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[In a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108545/adverse-or-averse)*** on the meanings of adverse and averse (now closed), *John Lawler* notes their similarities:

> They come from a common root that indicates turning. Averse (stressed
>   on the second syllable) is an adjective that means turning away from
>   something in dislike (He's averse to politics), while adverse
>   (stressed on the first syllable) is an adjective that describes (and
>   often modifies) circumstances, meaning that the situation has turned
>   on one and become difficult (In adverse conditions like this blizzard,
>   they won't expect you at work); the "turning" is metaphorical, but
>   it's enough to confuse. – John Lawler Mar 26 '13 at 14:18

While the conventional use of "averse" is "he is averse to" something, it's within stylistic convention to say, e.g., "Never have I seen anyone more politics-averse."  As a comment points out, "risk-averse" is common.

MW notes in its definition of averse that it's commonly used in compounds:

> ```
> :  having an active feeling of repugnance, dislike, or distaste —usually used with to She was not averse to taking chances. He seems
> ```
>
> to be averse to strenuous exercise. —commonly used in compounds both
>   with and without a hyphen a conservative risk-averse investor *a crowd
>   averse teen*

In addition to risk-averse, Google Ngram shows -averse with the noun modifiers inflation, loss, inequality, change, conflict, work, tax, debt, and technology.

"train-averse" (I'd add the hyphen because this is a compound adjective) is fine.  "Train-averse people are more likely to rent cars than those who enjoy trains."

Comment: Not sure if the OP asked about using adverse instead of averse.

Comment: The OP didn't; Lawler's comment covers both.  No point in separating them.

Comment: But there is no supporting evidence here that (1) 'N-averse' is productive enough to license eg 'porridge-averse', 'wolverine-averse' and in particular 'train-averse'; (2) 'N-averse' is hyphenated even when used predicatively. 'Lawler's comment covers both' is disingenuous.

Comment: Lawler's comment covers adverse and averse--that's what I meant.  Why do I need supporting evidence?  It's a fully grammatical and meaningful use.

Comment: Words aren't grammatical. They exist or the strings aren't words. Can you find a dictionary listing 'train-averse'? If not, this is a nonce usage, and the meaning is not clear as there is nowhere to check on it (averse to using trains, or averse to trains per se). // John Lawler's answer does not address the possibility of compounding, which is the essence of this question.